# list to array conversion issue

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to convert list to array and getting data format issue for the same. Code snippet below:

### Input

```
f=open('crime_rates.csv','r')
data=f.read()
data_row = data.split('\n')
print(data_row[0:5])
```

### Output

```
['Albuquerque,749', 'Anaheim,371', 'Anchorage,828', 'Arlington,503', 'Atlanta,1379']
```

### Next code Input

```
int_crime_rates=[]
for rows in data_row:
    crime_rates=rows.split(',')
    int_crime_rates.append(crime_rates)
print(int_crime_rates)
```

### Output

```
[['Albuquerque', '749'], ['Anaheim', '371'], ['Anchorage', '828'], ['Arlington', '503'], ['Atlanta', '1379']]
```

### Next code Input

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array(int_crime_rates)
print(arr)
```

### Output

```
[['Albuquerque' '749']
 ['Anaheim' '371']
 ['Anchorage' '828']
 ['Arlington' '503']
 ['Atlanta' '1379' ]]
```

Commas are missing between the elements e.g. i was expecting below result set

```
[['Albuquerque', '749'],
 ['Anaheim', '371'],
 ['Anchorage', '828'],
 ['Arlington', '503'],
 ['Atlanta', '1379' ]]
```

What is removing the commas? How to retain it?

Comment: Arrays display without commas, lists with.

Comment: Why do you expect the third `output` to be the same as the `second`?

Comment: coz  we are just converting list of lists to array. what i observed is that print(arr) shows the elements without commas, however if i type variable arr  in the input command line, it shows the values properly with commas in the output.

Comment: The `str()` (used by `print`) of an array displays without commas, the `repr()` shows commas and the `array` name.  Both displays are `proper`.  That's a convention that `numpy` has used for years.  See also the output of `np.array_str` and `np.array_repr`.

Comment: `arr.tolist()` converts the array back to a list, which always displays with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a list :-)

```
newArr = list(map(list, arr))
```

newArr **should** be a list **with** commas.